# How to get custom module configuration gui to send info to another web server?

Tags: magento

Firstly, I have to admit I am new to Magento and PHP. I am writing the configuration for my custom module. I would like to allow entry of some information, then send that information to a servlet on my web server where it is processed and a response returned and displayed in the configuration gui in a read-only field.

I am getting my guidance from various web articles and by looking at other modules' code. A module that does something similar is the PayPal module. However, it brings up a new browser window where the user logs in and enters their details. I just want to send the data gathered and wait for the response.

In my system.xml file I specify a frontend_model. In that frontend_model, the _prepareLayout method sets the template to my template, and in that template I have an HTML button. I added an onClick event handler to that button which makes an AJAX call to my web site. Unsurprisingly (because of the same origin policy I assume) the AJAX call fails with a code of 0.

I guess what I should be doing is when the user clicks the button, the request including the data they have entered in the other fields, is sent to the Magento server, and the AJAX call to my web site is made from there? Or perhaps my approach is completely wrong and there is a more appropriate way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're right about the same origin policy. The best approach here would be to have the button  trigger an ajax call to a local magento based controller, which itself uses curl or some other http request library to forward on a request to your remote servlet and process the feedback.

Comment: I got this working using the method suggested by Anton (although CORS, not JSONP). but I think the controller method sounds a nicer solution. Being new to Magento, I read up on Controllers on Alan Storm's site, but it only talks about controllers from the perspective of a URL being typed into a browser. I don't know how to get hold of a controller from my phtml file. In the javascript on my .phtml page I tried doing this <?php echo get_class(Mage::getController("mymodule/mycontroller")); ?> just to see if I could get hold of the controller, but it fell over on that line. Help?

Answer (score 0):

Try searching here "JSONP" or google the same thing. Dependent of javascript library you are using there are pre-made components/plugins to achieve what you are after.